# Significant in bivariate regression, but not significant in multivariate regression

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

I have two variables A and B, predicting X.

The variables were entered in a two stage hierarchical multiple regression, with variable A entered in Stage 1, and Variable B entered in Stage 2.

The results show that A was significant in the bivariate model, but when B was entered, A turns out to be non-significant.

How do I interpret this? Thanks in advance for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

To what degree are variables A and B correlated? If they are correlated then the issue at hand could be multicollinearity. Basically by itself A can significantly predict X, but when B is introduced it turns out it may be a better predictor of X and some of the predicted variance attributable to A now gets attributed to B, reducing the overall significance of variable A.